# focus fields on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, focus

I have 5 fields on my screen. I work on 9300 not a touch device

```
--------       ---------
   1              2
--------       ---------
------------------------
            3'/3''
-------------------------
            4
------------------------
```

I want when I click field 1 the focus change to the field 3'and if I click field 2 the focus change to field 3''. And when I click the down button the focus change to field 4.

What I have know the focus was in field 1 then 2 then 3''. I can't access  to field 3' or pass to field 4.
How can I order the focus of fields 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The order that the focus is transferred through your fields is normally determined by the order in which you `add()` them to their containing `Manager`.

You didn't completely specify how **all** of the transitions should work, but something like this might work:

```java
public void MyManager(long style) {
   super(style);

    Field one = new LabelField("hello");
    Field two = new BitmapField(image);
    Field threePrime = new EditField("");
    Field threeDoublePrime = new EditField("");
    Field four = new LabelField("goodbye");

    add(one);
    add(threePrime);
    add(two);
    add(threeDoublePrime);
    add(four);
}
```

If you want something more complicated than this, you can [override `navigationMovement(int,int,int,int)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#navigationMovement%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) in your custom `Manager` subclass (the `Manager` that contains these five `Field` objects).

[See this post for information about that technique.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-move-focus-left-right-up-down/m-p/101326/highlight/true#M11384)